# WPF - How to model a loop operation in the UI

Tags: wpf, multithreading, loops

I am creating a quick'n'dirty utility that will enable editing of data read sequentially from a set of files. Here's a very simplified explanation of what will happen in a single iteration of a loop:

- Read a line from the input stream
- Parse it and use the parsed results to populate form controls
- Allow user editing and await a confirmation button click
- Retrieve the updated form control values and write to the output stream

What I can't figure out is how to integrate the processing loop with the event-driven UI. For example, how do I suspend operation of the loop while waiting for user input.

I understand that this is possible by launching the loop operation on its own thread and writing code to manage its interaction with the UI thread, but I am wondering if there is a simpler approach that works out of the box.

Thanks for any ideas you may be able to offer.
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 2 approaches to do that:

- The easiest is probably to use a modal dialog: when your worker thread needs input from the user, display a dialog, which is a blocking operation. Something like that:

  ```
  // Worker thread loop
  while(...)
  {
      ...

      // prompt user for data (invoke synchronously on UI thread)
      UserData data = (UserData)window.Invoke(PromptUserData);

      ...
  }

  ...



  UserData PromptUserData()
  {
      UserInputDialog dlg = new UserInputDialog();
      dlg.ShowDialog();
      return dlg.UserData;
  }
  ```
- The other option, if you don't want to use a modal dialog, is to use a wait handle to synchronize the worker thread and the UI:

  private readonly AutoResetWaitHandle _userInputWaitHandle = new AutoResetWaitHandle(false);

  ```
  ...

  // Worker thread loop
  while(...)
  {
      ...

      // Setup the UI to allow user input
      window.Invoke(SetupUIForInput);
      // Wait for the input to be validated
      _userInputWaitHandle.WaitOne();
      ...
  }


  ...

  void SetupUIForInput()
  {
      // Enable the UI
      inputForm.Enabled = true;

      // Whatever else you need to do...
      ...
  }


  void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // Signal the worker thread to continue
      _userInputWaitHandle.Set();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't really implement a loop in the narrow sense.
You would do something like this (pseudo code):

```
OnStartOperationButtonClick()
{
    if(!ReadLine())
        return;
    ParseLineAndPopulateControls();
    ShowEditingControls();
}

OnConfirmationButtonClick()
{
    GetControlValuesAndWriteToOutputStream();
    if(!ReadLine())
    {
        HideEditingControls();
        return;
    }

    ParseLineAndPopulateControls();
}
```

No need for a separate thread, **given** that reading and parsing the line doesn't take long.